# Installing adobe-flashplugin on Ubuntu 16.10 for Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, 16.10, adobe

I am trying to install `adobe-flashplugin` on Ubuntu 16.10 for Firefox. I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

which throws the following error:

```
Err:0 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick/partner i386 adobe-flashplugin i386 11.2.202.228-0maverick1
  Insufficient information available to perform this download securely
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA1:bff9666cc9f108ae59833a0f44c2499f0a0dd261 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:b92c92245c190c7dc9d4a9bb4bd780c3 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:6591116 [weak]
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick/partner i386 adobe-flash-properties-gtk i386 11.2.202.228-0maverick1
  Insufficient information available to perform this download securely
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA1:5ea9ea111686652665cfca3aa1320b064c4f458f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2ed1fadfb6a07c3ca8ba9b8f3c774edc [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:131074 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.228-0maverick1_i386.deb  Insufficient information available to perform this download securely
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA1:bff9666cc9f108ae59833a0f44c2499f0a0dd261 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:b92c92245c190c7dc9d4a9bb4bd780c3 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:6591116 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.228-0maverick1_i386.deb  Insufficient information available to perform this download securely
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA1:5ea9ea111686652665cfca3aa1320b064c4f458f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2ed1fadfb6a07c3ca8ba9b8f3c774edc [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:131074 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maverick?? Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file seems to be somewhat dated. Please run the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep partner` and let us know the output by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson for your comments. I removed maverick entries. Now if I run sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin , it throws the following error: Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate . Any thoughts.

Comment: You shouldn't have removed them, but rather edited them to `yakkety` instead of `maverick`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
```

and run

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are pulling from an old repository.

Go to **Software & Updates>Other software.**

Then remove the old repository called:

```
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

Then enable the **'Canonical Partners'** repository.

If it doesn't exist, click add and type in:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
```

Next, run:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Flash Player should now be installed. Restart your browser for changes to take effect.